# display an extrafield over product image with virtuemart when typed by user (something like tshirt designer)

Tags: attributes, joomla, field, virtuemart

i need to display an extrafield (virtuemart standard attribute) on flypage over the product image.

I need it as a "customization print option" to display what user want to write over product!

I need the field under other extrafield (as it is normally), but let it appear over image only when user write on it! Is it possible?

Or is there some other solution for this?

Here's the example:
[image]

I'm using:

- Joomla V 1.5.14
- Virtuemart V1.1.6

code are welcome, i'm not so expert!
thank you

Comment: You might want to link your example here, its kind of hard to understand what it is you are asking for, functionally. Maybe if we see what you are referring to as the image or over the image, we can get a better idea on how this can be accomplished and advise accordingly.

Comment: i've added an example of the results.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that comes to mind is to use Mootools (since VM already loads it) to update a blank div that you position over the top of the image. This is a built in function in Mootools.

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3areplaces

Comment: could you provide the code? i need the same field duplicated 2 time as u can see on the image